# Single Sign on with Communities and Azure AD

Tags: community, single-sign-on

We are in the process of setting up Single Sign on for customer communities but we have an issue in getting it to work. We already set up Single Sign on with Azure AD for our internal Salesforce users and this works fine. We are not clear however how we need to configure Azure AD to also work with the community.

In Salesforce documentation it says that we need to pas the community URL in the Recipient attribute, but i am not clear how we can set this up in Azure AD.

```
 <saml:Subject>
         <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:
            nameid-format:unspecified">saml_portal_user_federation_id
         </saml:NameID>

         <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:
            SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
         <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter=
            "2009-06-17T18:48:25.456Z" 
            Recipient="https://acme.force.com/customers/login/?​saml=02HKiPoin4f49GRMsOdFmhTgi_​0nR7BBAflopdnD3gtixujECWpxr9klAw"/>
         </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml:Subject>
```

Can this be done with communities instead of the old customer portal? How do you populate this Recipient tag?